# Left join resulting in wrong values

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

When I execute this query:

```
select CONTA_ANALITICA_GERAL,
    DESIGNACAO_CC as CENTRO_CUSTO,
    sum(VALOR) as TOTAL
from VER_CNTORC_REAL_MES
where ANO = EXTRACT(year from sysdate)
    and MES = 2
    and CONTA_ANALITICA_AUXILIAR > 0
    and CONTA_FINANCEIRA_GERAL like '62%'
group by CONTA_ANALITICA_GERAL,
        DESIGNACAO_CC
```

I get the following result:

[image]

But when i try to do a left join with another table (so after i can join with a third to get the name associated with the "conta_analitica_geral" field) with this query:

```
select A.DESIGNACAO_CC,
       A.CONTA_ANALITICA_GERAL,
       B.CONTA_ANALITICA,
       sum(A.VALOR) as TOTAL
from VER_CNTORC_REAL_MES A
left join VER_MOVIMENTOS_CNT B on A.CONTA_ANALITICA_GERAL = B.CONTA_ANALITICA
where A.MES between 1 and 12
      and A.ANO = 2015
      and A.MES = 2
      and A.CONTA_ANALITICA_AUXILIAR > 0
      and A.CONTA_FINANCEIRA_GERAL like '62%'
group by A.DESIGNACAO_CC,
         A.CONTA_ANALITICA_GERAL,
         B.CONTA_ANALITICA
```

I get this result, with  the exact same number of results, the same "conta_analitica" ids, but with completely wrong values:

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks Ameya, i did, but the result is exactly the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When doing the left join you hit several rows in the joined table.
By grouping the result, you sum up every entry in those rows, resulting in a multiple of your wanted result.

For example (row one): 29,175.57/3,241.73 = 9; That means you have 9 rows in the joined table.

Comment: Thanks! what i did was:
On the left join, instead of the table name, i did "select unique conta_analitica from table".